# OutOfMemoryException while trying to send large json data to server in android?

Tags: java, android, json, out-of-memory

I am trying to send multiple Json string[each 1 MB] at a time to PHP Server. When i tried to send 10 records its working fine. But if it exceeds 20 records it says `OutOfMemoryException`. I seen that android memory size limit t0 15MB - 16MB. But haven't got any clue how to resolve this,
I am using the below code to send multiple records at a time.

```
 /** Upload Data*/
private void submitUploadData(String url, Map<String, String> param)
        throws IOException {
    URL siteUrl;
    try {
        siteUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        String content1 = ""; 

        Set getkey = param.keySet();
        Iterator keyIter = getkey.iterator();
        String content = "";
        for (int i = 0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
            Object key = keyIter.next();
            if (i != 0) {
                content += "&"; //Crashing here
            }
            content += key + "=" + param.get(key); //Crashing here
            System.out.println("Content" + content);
        }

        System.out.println(content);
        out.writeBytes(content.trim());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String jsonresponse = "";
        while ((jsonresponse = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(jsonresponse);   
            if(!jsonresponse.equals("Authorisation Successful")){
            updateUploadRecords(jsonresponse);}

        }
        in.close();  

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: It may be that your dataset is just too large. Some quick comments - 1) You appear to be creating a query string, keep in mind that most proxies will limit the length of query strings. 2) You are constructing your `content` string in the ***worst*** possible way.

Comment: use a stringbuilder to build your content (or keyvalue pairs, or textutils.join ...)

Comment: @perception what will be the right way to constructing the content?

Comment: @Vino - use a `StringBuilder`, its much more efficient.

Comment: @Perception Thanks I will change that. Just one doubt will changing to StringBuilder solve this issue?

Comment: @Vino - not necessarily, if you are dealing with an inordinate amount of data then probably not. Since you are coding a mobile app you do need to be memory conscious. Consider changing your service to accept chunked data, or request more memory from the device (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587722/android-java-get-more-allowed-memory-usage) for Android).

Comment: @Perception thanks i will have a look at it and try to solve this dam issue..

Comment: Please `refrain` from adding random `code` formatting to words in your question.  It makes text hard to read.

Comment: @charles sure in future question and answers. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at first glance there's nothing wrong with your code but you're using every possible type of method that is known for being a memory waster and now that you're trying large operations you running out of memory, that was guaranteed to happen.

tips:

- do not contatenate strings with `str1 += str2 + "other val"` you just created 3 new strings in memory. Use a StringBuilder instead.
- Calling System.gc() (as some will suggest you) will not help you, because you're in a Loop doing this operation and that method only hints the system that it might be a good time to GC, but until the system actually get around to do it, you'll have crashed already.
- If each JSON string is around 1mb and you're passing 20 of them, you're already crashing with out of memory on older devices right there with those 20mb. You'll have to re-design quite a few stuff, but my suggestion is to just remove the Map, completely remove it.

Instead you should (on the method that is creating that map) to use some type of `OutputStream`to write all that data, already formatted in a temporary file. Then, to upload you'll use some type of `InputStream` to read from this file and write to your `DataOutputStream`

Alternative to the Streams is to use some other classes that bases on the same methodology as streams, they are: JsonWriter/JsonReader, but then you also have FileWriter/FileReader if it's not specific Json what you're passing, and don't forget to always wrap those with BufferedReader and BufferedWriter.

Comment: Hi Budius, Thanks for your detailed answer with tips. This app is only for tablets, so no problem with the older devices. I will replace the string with StringBuilder.

Comment: it's not a matter of new/old devices. It's a matter of a code that will always work against a code that only works under very easy conditions. The moment you're passing 60 or 80 strings instead of 20, even your Nexus 10 will crash!

Comment: yes you are right i have to go for `JSONWriter` as you suggested +1

Answer (score 2):

Through personal experience I've found that beyond a certain size (which is dependent on the device), it is not feasible to use String concatenation to form / download entities.

In your case using a [JsonWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonWriter.html) will help. It writes json tokens to a stream and will not occupy additional memory. When you download bulky json documents use a [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html).

I've used both these classes with success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is limited by the memory size of your virtual device!?

Have you tried it by giving it a bigger memory!?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to increase that?

Comment: what ide do you use? I can only tell you for eclipse. There you can use avd manager which you find in Window->Android Virtual Device Manager...there you can create a virtual device with custom values for ram, vm heap, internal storage etc. etc....

Comment: I am using eclipse. So no problem i think

Comment: Oh sorry. I am talking about real devices Paul.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through it with object. You have the risk that they keep copies etc...
Go back to basics and try to use the function `String.split('');` and then iterating through it with a normal loop.
Then you know which objects are in memory. When doing the split you get two memory hogging objects, the original string and the array resulting from the split.

At the moment you have split the original string you can set the original string to `null` to free up the memory for the garbage collector(maybe even call `System.gc()`)

Then just simply loop through the string doing manipulation by manipulation, keeping the footprint as small as possible.